# Mix of parameter and command substitutions

Tags: zsh, substitution

I found this snippet of code (simplified)

```
while read item; do
  echo -n "${(q)item} "
done
```

from here https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.zsh#L12

I don't understand the expression `"${(q)item} "`.

What is variable `q`, I didn't find any declaration of it, is it a command substitution? Why parentheses use inside curly braces? What is meaning of this construction?

Comment: That's `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: See [Parameter Expansion Flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) in the `zsh` manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses immediately after `${` specify  [parameter expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags). The `q` flag is used to quote special characters in the expansion.

> Quote characters that are special to the shell in the resulting words with backslashes; unprintable or invalid characters are quoted using the $'\NNN' form, with separate quotes for each octet.